# Too many open files urllib

Tags: python, urllib

I'm having a problem with processing over 2700 files
This works if I have a little bit of a files like a couple of hundred, and I'm guessing it has to do with windows limiting open files like in linux ulimit can be definied system wide. I'm sure things are not being closed and this is why I am getting this error.

I have a function that sends a file via post:

```
def upload_photos(url_photo, dict, timeout):
    photo = dict['photo']
    data_photo = dict['data']
    name = dict['name']
    conn = requests.post(url_photo, data=data_photo, files=photo, timeout=timeout)
    return {'json': conn.json(), 'name': name}
```

which is called from a loop of a directory listing:

```
for photo_path in [p.lower() for p in photos_path]:
        if ('jpg' in photo_path or 'jpeg' in photo_path) and "thumb" not in photo_path:
            nr_photos_upload +=1
    print("Found " + str(nr_photos_upload) + " pictures to upload")
    local_count = 0
    list_to_upload = []
    for photo_path in [p.lower() for p in photos_path]:
        local_count += 1
        if ('jpg' in photo_path or 'jpeg' in photo_path) and "thumb" not in photo_path and local_count > count:
            total_img = nr_photos_upload
            photo_name = os.path.basename(photo_path)
            try :
                photo = {'photo': (photo_name, open(path + photo_path, 'rb'), 'image/jpeg')}
                try:
                    latitude, longitude, compas = get_gps_lat_long_compass(path + photo_path)
                except ValueError as e:
                    if e != None:
                        try:
                            tags = exifread.process_file(open(path + photo_path, 'rb'))
                            latitude, longitude = get_exif_location(tags)
                            compas = -1
                        except Exception:
                            continue
                if compas == -1:
                    data_photo = {'coordinate'    : str(latitude) + "," + str(longitude),
                               'sequenceId'       : id_sequence,
                               'sequenceIndex'    : count
                               }
                else :
                    data_photo = {'coordinate'    : str(latitude) + "," + str(longitude),
                               'sequenceId'       : id_sequence,
                               'sequenceIndex'    : count,
                               'headers'          : compas
                               }
                info_to_upload = {'data': data_photo, 'photo':photo, 'name': photo_name}
                list_to_upload.append(info_to_upload)
                count += 1
            except Exception as ex:
                print(ex)
    count_uploaded = 0
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers) as executor:
        # Upload feature called from here
        future_to_url = {executor.submit(upload_photos, url_photo, dict, 100): dict for dict in list_to_upload}
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
            try:
                data = future.result()['json']
                name = future.result()['name']
                print("processing {}".format(name))
                if data['status']['apiCode'] == "600":

                    percentage = float((float(count_uploaded) * 100) / float(total_img))
                    print(("Uploaded - " + str(count_uploaded) + ' of total :' + str(
                        total_img) + ", percentage: " + str(round(percentage, 2)) + "%"))
                elif data['status']['apiCode'] == "610":
                    print("skipping - a requirement arguments is missing for upload")
                elif data['status']['apiCode'] == "611":
                    print("skipping - image does not have GPS location metadata")
                elif data['status']['apiCode'] == "660":
                    print("skipping - duplicate image")
                else :
                    print("skipping - bad image")
                count_uploaded += 1
                with open(path + "count_file.txt", "w") as fis:
                    fis.write((str(count_uploaded)))
            except Exception as exc:
                print('%generated an exception: %s' % (exc))
```

Comment: So, the problem is in simulatanious processing of too many files. May be the simplest way to fix it is following: do not stop if there is any problem, but wait few milliseconds and repeat (be careful to avoid infinite loop). In this case all the files will be processed.

Comment: In common cases is rarely beneficial to upload more than a handful of files at the same time, especially when you are hammering the same server. Ease down on the number of simultaneous connections.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `_setmaxstdio` in C to change the number of files which can be opened at a time.

For python you have to use `win32file` from `pywin32` as:

```
import win32file
win32file._setmaxstdio(1024) #set max number of files to 1024
```

The default is `512`. And make sure you check max value you set is supported by your platform.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e3b887c.aspx

Comment: "maximum number of open files" is that kind of limit that nowadays is high enough that should make you question your algorithm, not find ways to alter the limit...

Comment: This option doesn't work and what Matteo said, it's not best practice to do something like this